# Is the empty set considered a conic?

Tags: conic-sections

If the graph of the equation $Ax^2+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ 
is the empty set (no point at all), is it considered a conic? Isn't a conic supposed to be the intersection of a plane and a cone?

Comment: There is no universal rule. People approaching conics from the equation $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ probably regard $x^2+y^2+1=0$ as a degenerate conic. People starting from a geometrical viewpoint probably do not.

Comment: @almagest That's just a circle of radius $i$

Comment: True, but I assume the OP is only interested in real points.

Comment: A "conic" or "conic section" is the intersection of a plane with a (double) cone.  Any plane at all will intersect such a cone in at least one point.  So, no, the empty set is not a "conic".

Answer (score 2):

The graph is empty only if you're dealing with strictly real coordinates. Otherwise there's always a solution by the fundamental theorem of algebra. So you see, it all depends on context ($\mathrm R$ or $\mathrm C$) whether you consider all such equations as representing conics, or only those having real points.